# Joining two whole tables on bigquery

Tags: datatables, google-bigquery, join

So I have two tables on bigquery. One is a list of data that I saved as a table after I queried the data from a larger table. The other is an excel spreadsheet with more information about the data. On both tables they are organized by serial numbers. How do I join the two tables.

Table 1 = Model_results
Table 2 = Master_list

This is what I have tried but keep getting this error. 
Error: Encountered " "-" "- "" at line 1, column 24. Was expecting: < EOF >

```
SELECT * FROM dataworks-356fa:FirebaseArchive.Model_Results
JOIN dataworks-356fa:FirebaseArchive.Master_List on Serial_Number=Serial
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below (which uses BigQuery Legacy SQL notion)

```sql
SELECT * FROM [dataworks-356fa:FirebaseArchive.Model_Results]
JOIN [dataworks-356fa:FirebaseArchive.Master_List] on Serial_Number=Serial
```

For BigQuery Standard SQL it will be

```sql
SELECT * FROM `dataworks-356fa.FirebaseArchive.Model_Results`
JOIN `dataworks-356fa.FirebaseArchive.Master_List` on Serial_Number=Serial
```